# Why is confidence interval greater than 1 for binary data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have binary data and I want to calculate the confidence interval for that, but why do I get the upper bound greater than 1?
Here is my code

```
import math
def find_CI(a):
    n = len(a)
    p_hat = sum(a)/n
    h = math.sqrt((p_hat * (1- p_hat) /n))
    ub = p_hat + (1.96 * h)
    lb = p_hat - (1.96 * h)
    return lb, ub
```

When I pass a = [1,0,0,1,1], I get the result (0.17058551491594975, 1.0294144850840503)

I also tried the following code

```
import scipy.stats as st
def find_confidence_interval(a):
    x = st.t.interval(alpha=0.95, df=len(a)-1,
              loc=np.mean(a),
              scale=st.sem(a))
    return x
```

I got the result as (-0.08008738065825705, 1.280087380658257)

I am confused. Shouldn't the confidence interval be between 0 and 1?

Comment: What's the significance of `1.96`?

Comment: It is the critical value for 95% confidence interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a t-statistic to calculate confidence intervals for binomial data is probably not a good idea because this means you are assuming your data comes from an approximately normal distribution.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1) for details on how to more appropriately deal with confidence intervals in binomial distributions. For example, you could use the [Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) interval if you don't have many data points. For your [1, 1, 1, 0, 0] example a Wilson 95% interval would give (0.23, 0.88)